# How to print array data in Yii2

Tags: php

Good afternoon! I'm trying to add multiple arrays to a single array. This is why I try to generate a csv file and add arrangements as new rows are added to .csv

Static example:

```
$data = array(
            array( 'item' => 'Server',  'cost' => 10000, 'approved by' => 'Joe bebe'),
            array( 'item' => 'Mt Dew',  'cost' => 1.25,  'approved by' => 'John'),
            array( 'item' => 'Intelli', 'cost' => 500,   'approved by' => 'James')
);

$this -> outputCsv('document.csv', $data);
```

I want to try something like this:

```
$array = ('Juan', 'Pedro', 'Luis')

$data = array(
foreach($array as $a):
         array( 'item' => $a,  'cost' => 10000, 'approved by' => 'Joe'),
endforeach;

 $this -> outputCsv('document.csv', $data);
```

Comment: [have you tried using a loop?](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Yes, but I can not put in loop within the array

Comment: huh, well best of luck with that then :/

Comment: Sorry but can you reword your question giving examples of the inputs and the desired outputs. Currently nobody knows what you are actually trying to achieve or what your data looks like.

Comment: Ready, and un updating @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array = array('Juan', 'Pedro', 'Luis');
$data = array();
foreach($array as $a)
      $data[] = array( 'item' => $a,  'cost' => 10000, 'approved by' => 'Joe');
$this->outputCsv('document.csv', $data);
```

Perhaps?

Comment: Thanks! @sam, but not works...
**This webpage is not available**
ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE

Comment: @Annon Can you post your code on pastebin so i can check out?

Comment: Actually so it should work , if I take the first under $ data if it works but without the name of the columns..
`$data[] = [ 
                        [
                        'EmpCheca' => $value['Id'],
                        ]   
                    ];`

Comment: @Annon Can't you add it to the foreach?

Comment: @Annon see first comment :)